# Use Docker to keep track of software versions/installations?

Tags: docker

I have an data processing application which is updated on a regular basis. This application has a bunch of dependencies which are also updated every now and then. However, different versions of the software (+dependencies) might produce different results (this is expected). The application is run on a remote computer and it can be accessed through a Web page. Every time the user uses the Web page to do some processing she/he also chooses which version of the software he/she wants to use.

Now I am trying to decide which is the best way of keeping track different software (+dependencies) versions. The simplest way of course is to just compile and install each version of my software and its dependencies in a different folder, and then based on the request the user sends, the appropriate folder is selected. However, this sounds very clunky to me. So I thought I could use Docker to keep track of the different software versions. Do you think that it is a good idea? If yes, what is most appropriate to do every time I have a new version of the software (and/or dependencies): 1) Create a new container from scratch with the new version (and end up having multiple containers), or 2) Update the existing container and commit the changes? (I suppose I can access the older commits of the container, right?)

PS: Keep in mind that the reason I looked into Docker and not a simple virtual machine solution is that the application I am running is a high-performance GPU-based software.

Comment: Don't update containers. Make a new image, start a new container. Containers are supposed to be disposable, if you have any state in them, externalize that state (to a database or volume mount).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker is a reasonable choice.  Your repository would contain all of the app versions you wish to publish.  Note, you will only realize savings if you organize the resulting app filesystem into layers, of which the lower layers are the least likely to change between versions.  This will keep the storage requirements at a minimum.

Then you have to decide how you will process each job.  A robust (but complex) solution would be to have one or more API containers which take in processing jobs from your user and "dole" them out to worker containers (one or more from each release version).  This would provide the lowest response latency and be non-blocking.  You can look at different service discovery models to see how your "worker" containers can register with your "manager" containers.  This is probably more than you'd like to bite off, but consider using a good key-value database (another container!) like etcd or a 3rd party service discovery tool like zookeeper/eureka/consul.

A much simpler model would have a single API container with one each of the release containers created, but not started.  The API container would start, direct, and then stop the appropriate release container.  You would incur the startup latency, but this is the least resource intensive... and easiest to manage.  But this is a blocking operation.

Somewhere in the middle, but less user friendly is to have each release container running but listening on different host ports (the app always sees the same port).  The user would would connect to the port which is servicing the desired release of the app.  You'd have to provide some sort of index to make this useful.